# How to use vertex_index_t on Boost Graph Library?

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

I know this is a very simple question, but I've been searching it for a long time and I haven't found the simple answer.

I have defined an adjacency_list matrix in this form:

```
typedef adjacency_list<vecS, listS, undirectedS, Person> Network;
```

which "Person" is a class defined somewhere in my code. (I'm using bundled properties)

as you can see, my matrix is using vecS for storing vertices so I should have a builtin index set, now how can I get the indexes (or initialize them if necessary) while I run a loop in the following form?

```
VertexIterator i, end;
for (tie(i, end) = vertices(graph); i != end; i++)
{}
```

Is that even possible when you use bundled properties?

I have tried to work with the get() function but didn't find the result I wanted.
I also have tried the [boost graph library documentations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/graph/doc/using_property_maps.html) but they are extremely short and offer no examples in this part.

Comment: "my matrix is using vecS for storing vertices" [Nope, you are storing vertices in a list and edges in a vector](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html).

Comment: Oh! I get it now, it was all because the documentation started with the vertexList type and I thought the first option for the vertices is a vector. thanks!